# Django Stripe API Key Issues

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, stripe-payments

I have these lines (among other things) in my Django base settings file:

```
import os
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY", "your publishable test key")
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY", "your secret test key")
```

I created those two environment variables in my virtualenv like this:

```
export STRIPE_SECRET_KEY="sk_test_example"
export STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY="pk_test_example"
```

When I run env | grep STRIPE, I get this:

```
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_example
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY=pk_test_example
```

But for some reason, I keep getting this Stripe error: ""Invalid API Key provided: \"\u003C**** ****** **** key\u003E\". This key contains at least one space. Please delete the spaces and try again."

I tried exporting the environment variables again, once without quotation marks and once with single quotation marks, and I got the same result, so I tried printing the STRIPE_SECRET_KEY and STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY from the settings file, and it returned the defaults, "your publishable test key" and "your secret test key". So that's why there were spaces. But why weren't the environment variables getting picked up?

So I tried getting rid of the defaults in my base settings so the variables look like this:

```
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY")
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY")
```

That threw a NoneType error. I also tried the following:

```
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY']
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
```

That threw "KeyError: u'STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY'". What do I need to change? I really don't want to hard-code these API keys.

Comment: Can you confirm what shell you're using?

Comment: Sure. I'm using bash.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I'd forgotten (argh) to export the environment variables in my virtualenv postactivate file and was running the server in a different window, so once I put the Stripe API keys in the postactivate file, I needed to deactivate and activate the virtualenv before running the server.

Answer (score 1):

For API keys, the quotes aren't necessary

```
export STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_example
export STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY=pk_test_example
```

It looks like the string format constructed with bash quotes is different than what Python is accepting. I don't know what formats these are, but this would definitely make sense.

Alternatively, you might want to look into a "dotenv" implementation such as [`django-dotenv`](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-dotenv).

This is a much more reliable way to work with strings like this. The problem is that when you're using different string formats (UTF-8 vs UTF-16 or Unicode), you may run into the situation where some program is expecting one format but receives another. The output you included is an example of what this looks like (hence my concern here).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that I tried it without quotation marks and still got the same error. I haven't heard of django-dotenv before. I'll look into it.

Comment: My bad, I missed that point! dotenv is my preferred method when working with any web framework (implementations exist for everything, and are easy to customize or implement yourself if needed). The point being that with a dotenv, you're loading the variables directly from the working environment.

Comment: If I install django-dotenv, I don't need to change anything about the way the variables are set in my settings files, do I?

Comment: You shouldn't have to! You could also try https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv. It's pretty much the same, and much better documented, but lacks some Django-specific functionality.

Comment: Yep. See my comment below.

Comment: Oh, sweet! I didn't notice it. Good to hear you've got it under control!